# Elasticsearch highlighting - not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following problem:

I'm doing some tests with facetings

My script is as follows:

https://gist.github.com/nayelisantacruz/6610862

the result I get is as follows:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": []
    },
    "facets": {
        "title": {
            "_type": "terms",
            "missing": 0,
            "total": 2,
            "other": 0,
            "terms": [
                {
                    "term": "JavaScript",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "term": "Java Platform, Standard Edition",
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

which is fine, but the problem is that I can not display the "highlighting"

I was expecting a result like the following:

..........
..........
..........

```
"facets": {
    "title": {
        "_type": "terms",
        "missing": 0,
        "total": 2,
        "other": 0,
        "terms": [
            {
                "term": "<b>Java</b>Script",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "term": "<b>Java</b> Platform, Standard Edition",
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

..........
..........
..........

Anyone can help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing, please

Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 8):

Faceting and highlighting are two completely different things. Highlighting works together with search, in order to return highlighted snippets for each of the search results.

Faceting is a completely different story, as a facet effectively looks at all the terms that have been indexed for a specific field, throughout all the documents that match the main query. In that respect, the query only controls the documents that are going to be taken into account to perform faceting. Only the top terms (by default with higher count) are going to be returned. Those terms are not only related to the search results (by default 10) but to all the documents that match the query.

That said, the terms returned with the facets are never highlighted.

If you use [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/highlighting/) you should see in your response, as mentioned in the reference, a new section that contains the highlighted snippets for each of your search results. The reason why you don't see it is that you are querying the `title.autocomplete` field, but you make highlighting on the `title` field with `require_field_match` enabled. You either have to set `require_field_match` to true or highlight the same field that you are querying on. But again this is not related to faceting whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

Note the use of `*` instead of `_all`. This works like a charm at all level of nesting:

```
POST 123821/Encounters/_search 
{ 
  "query": { 
    "query_string": { 
      "query": "Aller*" 
    } 
  }, 
  "highlight": { 
    "fields": { 
      "*": {} 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: For the reference for why "_all" does not work for nested fields https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html